# What are the maximum altitude and speed of a GT500 ultralight?

Tags: aircraft-performance, aircraft-limitations, ultralight

What are the maximum altitude and airspeed of a [GT500 ultralight](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksilver_GT500)?

Comment: All the information is in the Wikipedia article in the original post.  12,500ft,   90kts

Answer (score 1):

The service ceiling is 12,500 Feet MSL (Exactly 3,810 Meters), and the never exceed speed is 103 MPH (About 89.5 Knots).
Source 1: http://www.air-techinc.com/ultralight_aircraft_details.php?ptid=118

Source 2: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksilver_GT500#Specifications_.28GT500.29